# How do you indicate that a request is loading, and then change the UI once a request is finished, with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider this example using React hooks:

```
function async apiRequest(id) {
  return fetch('http://someurl.com/api/' + id)  
}

function ParentComponent() {
  [id, setId] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const newId = await apiRequest(id);
    setId(newId.result.id);
  }, [id])

  return (
     <>
       <p>ID is currently {id}</p>
       <ChildButton id={1} handleOnClick={setId} />
     </>
  )
}

function ChildButton({id, handleOnClick}) {
  render (
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleOnClick(id)} }>Click Me</button>
  )
}
```

Now suppose that I want to do 2 things:

- Show that the request is in progress after I push the button
- Make the button disappear after it's been clicked, and a successful request to the API has completed.

Assume that we can’t depend on a particular value being returned from the API.

What are the minimum steps I need to take to do this? Either I'm missing something, or it's very difficult to do this with React hooks.

Comment: Your title does not appear to be the same as your question body. Asking for "best practices" is likely to be closed as "opinion-based" because "best practices" are opinions voiced by people who label those opinions "best practices". If you want to ask how to make a button disappear after it's been clicked and reappear once the request is complete, ask that question.

Comment: What have you tried? Any effort to search for answer? Did you find a solution that you don't understand? What makes a solution both "Best Practice" and with  "Minimum steps"?

Comment: `{id && <ChildButton id={1} handleOnClick={setId} />}` ?

Comment: @TJ I assume this depends on 0 being falsy, which is brittle and would only work in this one case. I'm looking for a general solution to the problem of indicating that a request has started, and then doing something only when the request has finished.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm not looking for a solution to this exact problem, this is a simplified example. I assume it is a common use case to have a UI that triggers an action, and then does something in response to the action that the UI triggered once the action is complete, so I assume there must be a common way of doing this with React.

Answer (score 1):

don't know about best practices but you can.

```
const [clicked, setclicked] = useState(false);

const handleOnClick = () => {
  setClicked(true)
}

<p>ID is currently {id}</p>
if (!clicked && id === 0) {
   <ChildButton id={1} handleOnClick={handleOnClick} />
}
```